# Get Favourite day from data set

Tags: cloudant

I have data like this

State         City          Day

Arizona       Chandler      Monday

Arizona       Mesa          Wednesday

Arizona       Chandler      Monday

Arizona       Mesa          Saturday

Washington    Vancouver     Friday

Washington    Vancouver     Friday

Washington    Spokane       Monday

Washington    Vancouver     Tuesday

Washington    Spokane       Monday

I want to get favourite day by state and city

eg Favourite day for Washington-Vancouver is Friday and that for Arizon-Chandler is Monday

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using views. You could create your map function to emit the key as `[state, city, day]` with a value of `1` you could then use the `_count` reduce to see how many times each key is mentioned. From that you will be able to determine the favourite day for each state / city. You can read more about views in the [cloudant documentation](http://docs.cloudant.com/creating_views.html).

Answer (score 1):

So in JSON a document would look like this:

`{
  "state": "Arizona",
  "city": "Chandler",
  "day": "Monday"
}`

To find "favourite day by state and city" we can create an index where the key comprises of all three things:

`function(doc) {
    emit([doc.state,doc.city,doc.day], null);
  }`

And use the built-in `_count` reducer.

This will give keys like this:

```
["Arizona","Chandler","Monday"]
```

The counts then then be collected by interrogating the view:

/db/_design/mydesigndoc/_view/myview?group_level=3

which will give counts for each distinct combination of state/city/day.

It can't just return the "favourite"; only all the unique combinations and you would have to iterate through the result set to find the one with largest total.

Comment: Ok. Let me use this approach.

Comment: Hello Glynn, I also need to search them based on State and City. Means i would like to know favourite day for state, or state and city and for state, city and zip code.